# Child-class cannot be cast to generic parent class 

Tags: java, generics

If have a type hierarchy that starts out with a generic type

```
class A<T> { ... }
class B extends A<Qux> { ... }
class C extends B { ...}
```

So far so good. Now I have a different class (also a generic) that uses A as parameter:

```
class Foo<T> extends Bar<T> {
  setA(A<T> a){ ...}  
}
```

Now I want to use all this:

```
Foo<Qux> foo = new Foo<Qux>();
foo.setA(new C());
```

The last line gives an error "setA in type Foo is not application for the arguments C".

I can't figure out what's wrong. In my opinion it should work because C extends B which extends A, which is the the parameter type that should be used ... thanks for any hints what is wrong with my assumptions.

*Update:* Using the code posted by Oli, I managed to get closer to the source of the error. It occurs once I replace B with my original class. So it must be located in the class that does away with the "generic" part. When trying to cast to the parent class Eclipse says it can't. I'll keep looking there, I know it should be working ... the problem can be reduced to this:

```
C c = new C();
A<Qux> a = (A<Qux>)c;
```

In my code this results in the error

```
Cannot cast from C to A<Qux>
```

I still have no idea why this happens. **Is there any reason why a child class cannot be cast to it's parent class?** There is no such reason. Because if you have such a problem it might just be your IDE. I restarted Eclipse for other reasons, checked again and it worked.

Comment: I don't see the error that you mentioned (in your code, I assume `setA` is invoked on the `foo` instance declared above).

Comment: thx for the hint about the call

Comment: I am still looking ... filling in his code with my classes, to figure out what does happen. I'll update the question as soon as I find something

Comment: I was able to reduce the potential source of the error ... I cannot cast up the original hierarchy ... why? I have no idea.

Comment: @Yashima: I've updated the code in my answer to reflect the update to your question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following compiles fine for me:

```
public class Test {

    static class Qux {};

    static class A<T> {}
    static class B extends A<Qux> {}
    static class C extends B {}

    static class Bar<T> {}
    static class Foo<T> extends Bar<T> {
        void setA(A<T> a) {}
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo<Qux> foo = new Foo<Qux>();
        foo.setA(new C());

        // From question update
        C c = new C();
        A<Qux> a = c;
    }
}
```

Your problem must lie elsewhere.

Comment: oh thanks for the code anyway, I'll try to set up this test for the actual classes, maybe I made a mistake in writing the question.

Comment: thanks for your help in showing me how to test that it should work. it turns out after an Eclipse restart it compiles :( I am not sure this question is worth preserving now, since the original problem didn't exist at all.